# Getting Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, smalldatetime

I want to get all the information between two given dates, How can I get a range of Date in SQL server with the datatype of "smalldatetime"

I'm expecting to get all the information start from start date to end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this :

```
SELECT * 
from your_table
where date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```